# how to add css class to radio button in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-widget-tweaks

I am trying to do the following with django widget tweaks:

```
{{ form.gender.0.tag|attr:"class:radio_1" }}
```

I get the error:

> 'SafeText' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize your RadioButton like this:

```
CHOICES=[('option1','option1'),
         ('option2','option2')]

radio = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'radio_1'}))
```

and the generated HTML-Code will look like this:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio_1" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured out already how to apply CSS to radio buttons in Django template but in case someone is in the same situation, here's a code straight from the docs:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>{{ myform.beatles.label }}</legend>
    {% for radio in myform.beatles %}
    <div class="myradio">
        {{ radio }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</fieldset>
```

This code assumes you have a form **myform** with a field **beatles** that uses a **RadioSelect** as its widget.

As you can see, looping through the field **beatles** can allow you to add necessary classes (here class=*"myradio"*) for each radio button; hence, make your CSS styling possible and easier.

In your case, you might want to also loop through your **gender** field and then apply the appropriate classes.